# Marquee tag issue

Tags: html, css

I am new to coding in html and css,I am making a responsive web page, I have a text on the top of my page within a div, as I decrease the width of the browser the text gets cut from right side, I thought marquee could be a solution for the problem but i have heard its obsolete.So, how do m i fix my problem?Please let me know if the problem can be solved...

```
#topdiv
{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    height:20px;
}
#topdiv p
{
    position:relative;
    color:#FFF;
    float:right;
}
```

Comment: You need to have a look at media queries, they allow you to change the layout based on the screen width - https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: You should show mode code; what you have there is not enough to make the text cut off to the right. ([Example](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/c3j5k9or/).) Unless you have ***very*** long words. So, could you provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: Actually, to be specific, the text is with long words and when i decrease the width of the browser then it doesn't get needed space and instead shifting down it gets cut...I thought to make that text visible i can use marqee....I cannot explain the problem beyond this but thank you for your suggestions guyz...thanks @Andrew I used the media query to solve the problem  and it worked... so when the width of the browser is not sufficient for the text font will be reduced....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe this is what you want

```css
#topdiv
{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: right;
    width:100%;
    height:20px;
}
#topdiv p
{
    position:relative;
    color:red;
    /*float:right;*/
}
```

```html
<div id="topdiv">
<p>some text jfkdjfk fjkdfjkd fghjg fjsklfjsdklf fgsdfhusdgfjksdfsdl 123</p>
</div>
```

here is jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/dbdwdcrp/

Comment: I'm not sure the problem you solved here is the problem the OP is asking about.

Comment: I thought he says "I decrease the width of the browser the text gets cut from right side" so I gave him solution, but may be I didnt get his question

Answer (score 0):

Why you are using `position:fixed` if you need this then you need to remove width of parent div check below snippet

```css
 #topdiv {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    height: 20px;
    left: 0px;
    padding: 10px;
 }
 #topdiv p {
    color:#000;
    float:right;
    text-align:justify;
    margin:0;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="topdiv">
     <p>
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
      tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
      quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
      consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
      cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
      proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      <br><br>
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
      tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
      quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
      consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
      cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
      proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
     </p>
    </div>
```

if you don't need `fixed position` then update below css.

```
#topdiv {
    padding:10px;
}
```

```css
 #topdiv
    {
        padding:10px;
    }
    #topdiv p
    {
        color:#000;
        float:right;
        text-align:justify;
        margin:0;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="topdiv">
     <p>
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
      tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
      quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
      consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
      cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
      proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      <br><br>
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
      tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
      quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
      consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
      cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
      proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
     </p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use max-width style for topdiv

```
#topdiv {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    max-width:98%;
    height:20px;
}
```